# Is restricting permissions based on linux usernames instead of uid a secure method?

Tags: permissions, users, uid

Say you have a user called `foo` and a group called `foogroup`.

The uid for `foo` is 10000 and gid for `foogroup` is 20000.

If your program wants to restrict specific users, is checking the user name as secure as checking the uid?

As far as I know, modifying the username or the uid can only be done by modifying `/etc/passwd` or using `usermod`.

Answer (score 1):

The user name in linux is unique as like as the uid, so in my opinion checking the user name as secure as checking the uid.